# Convert List items as drop down menu without Jquery

Tags: css, angularjs

I've the list items as follows. I'm using an Angular JS application. I need to represent them as drop down menu simply by using CSS.  I should not include any JQuery js file

- English
- Español
- Française
- Italian

```
Here is my fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/CDrLV/
```

Can any one look into the following code?

Comment: This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CDrLV/

Comment: What did you try ? Paste some CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to hide the list with `display: none;` then show it again on hover.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RdNw4/1/) for an example

Comment: Looks fine, But, I need to click on it.. Not hover.. And one more thing is that, the page layout gets changed on hovering.

Comment: To do it on click you will need some javascript. The layout changed as i spelt absolute wrong in the CSS, see this [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/RdNw4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

with this you can http://jsfiddle.net/RdNw4/3/

But I don't know if it's work fine in IE. (probably not)

Help yourself with layout.

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <div>Select Language</div>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Español</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Française</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Italian</a></li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 50px;

    background: #f3f3f3;
} 

.nav {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;

    background: #fff;

    position: relative;
}

.nav ul {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: none;

    background: #fff;

    list-style: none;

    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.nav:hover ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

ps: I saw it here http://jsfiddle.net/UR4Up/

Comment: No.. You got me wrong. My scenario is like..Initially, english would be selected and it should be displayed, and if the user wants to change the language, he would click on the language to display the list of other languages. Just like language selection in any Airline website.

Comment: Ok! the CSS doesn't call events and functions. So you'll have to use Javascript.